# calculating running totals in separate columns in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
frame =  pd.DataFrame({'home' : ['CHI', 'ATL', 'SEA', 'DET', 'STL','HOU' ,'CHI','CHI'],
                   'away' : ['DET', 'CHI', 'HOU', 'TOR', 'DAL', 'STL', 'MIA', 'SEA']})
```

Thanks to **unutbu** I can keep a running total of total games played for each team like this.

```
awayGP = collections.Counter()
homeGP = collections.Counter()

def count_games():
    for idx, row in frame.iterrows():
        homeGP[row['home']] +=1
        awayGP[row['away']] +=1
        test = homeGP + awayGP
        yield awayGP[row['away']], awayGP[row['home']], , homeGP[row['away']], homeGP[row['home']]

frame['awayteamAwayGP'] , frame['hometeamAwayGP'], frame['awayteamHomeGP'],          frame['hometeamHomeGP'] = zip(*list(count_games()))                                                             
frame['awayteamGames'] =   frame['awayteamAwayGP'] + frame['awayteamHomeGP']                                                                                       
frame['hometeamGames'] =   frame['hometeamAwayGP'] + frame['hometeamHomeGP']        
del frame['awayteamAwayGP'] , frame['hometeamAwayGP'], frame['awayteamHomeGP'],    frame['hometeamHomeGP']
```

I would like to be able to keep running total of the points scored for each team.

```
frame['awayPTS'] = [88, 75, 105, 99, 110, 85, 95, 100]
frame['homePTS'] = [92, 88, 95, 97, 100, 74, 98, 110]
```

This is the desired output.

```
away  home  awayteamGP  hometeamGP awayPTS  homePTS awayteam_totalPTS hometeam_totalPTS 
 DET   CHI     1             1       88        92          88               92
 CHI   ATL     2             1       75        88          180              88
 HOU   SEA     1             1       105       95          105              95
 TOR   DET     1             2       99        97          99               187
 DAL   STL     1             1       110       100         110              100
 STL   HOU     2             2       85        74          185              179
 MIA   CHI     1             3       95        98          95               265
 SEA   CHI     2             4       100       110         195              375
```

Comment: It feels like there ought to be a neat way using stack (essentially separating into away/home, enabling a groupby apply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `defualtdict` (with default value 0) where you will keep the current scores of the teams, and apply along the `axis=1` a function that updates this dictionary and returns a tuple of results. Then just concatenate your DataFrame and the resulting DataFrame from the `apply` function along `axis=1`.

```
frame =  pd.DataFrame({
    'home'    : ['CHI', 'ATL', 'SEA', 'DET', 'STL','HOU' ,'CHI','CHI'],
    'away'    : ['DET', 'CHI', 'HOU', 'TOR', 'DAL', 'STL', 'MIA', 'SEA'],
    'awayPTS' : [88, 75, 105, 99, 110, 85, 95, 100],
    'homePTS' : [92, 88, 95, 97, 100, 74, 98, 110],
})

score = collections.defaultdict(int)
def calculate(row):
    away = row['away']
    home = row['home']
    score[away] += row['awayPTS']
    score[home] += row['homePTS']
    return pd.Series([score[away], score[home]],
                     index=['awayteam_totalPTS', 'hometeam_totalPTS'])
frame = pd.concat([frame, frame.apply(calculate, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Gives:

```
  away home  awayPTS  homePTS  awayteam_totalPTS  hometeam_totalPTS
0  DET  CHI       88       92                 88                 92
1  CHI  ATL       75       88                167                 88
2  HOU  SEA      105       95                105                 95
3  TOR  DET       99       97                 99                185
4  DAL  STL      110      100                110                100
5  STL  HOU       85       74                185                179
6  MIA  CHI       95       98                 95                265
7  SEA  CHI      100      110                195                375
```

Comment: FYI Counter is basically sugar for defaultdict(int)

Comment: @AndyHayden I know, I'm just used to `defaultdict` since it's around 4x faster.

Comment: stack/groupby/apply is *significantly* faster than this method (once there's more than 40 or so rows)!

Comment: And significantly more cryptic :D But I agree with you, if speed is the bottleneck he should use it. If not... Readability counts... :)

Comment: Actually I have to disagree with you (once you realise that cumsum works on each group) I think groupby.cumsum is clearer.

Comment: (hehe, the irony of your previous comment re Counter) :)

Comment: thanks everybody.  i will try both methods out for a while and let you know which one works out the best.

Comment: @AndyHayden Hah true for the Counter :) Actually I agree with you that grouping should be the preferred way of thinking when you use pandas, but I didn't knew the knowledge level of the OP so I tried to follow his intuition of doing it row-wise. But since we are comparing the methods, your is faster, but it takes at least twice as much memory since a stack cannot be a view and I don't know the implementation details of groupby so I cannot tell how much that costs (assuming that I did the same thing of appending columns and not concat).

Comment: I'm not sure about the memory (I would've thought it would be much less than the defaultdicts...), not sure if stack creates a copy (concat doesn't so it might not wither). Would be **shocked** if memory was larger for stack approach tbh, but happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: You're not including the memory of the defaultdicts (!) which are very inefficient (when compared to numpy!) both in terms of speed and space, they are the thing which slows you down. So it *may* be twice the arrays (I'm not sure either), but that doesn't mean twice the memory used overall. groupby/concat/cumsum all are very cheap, written in cython with numpy so fast and low memory.

Comment: @AndyHayden Just measured it. If the original data frame takes N memory, defaultdict version takes 6xN more memory, and the stack version takes 32xN more memory.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez this is very interesting, can you show me a gist?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez ah, reason is because size of defaultdicts scale with the number of teams, which is something you haven't scaled, so that's why it does better in this case... "lies, damned lies and statistics" :p

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes, you're right. I updated the gist and created 720 teams and all possible combinations for matches. Now the ratio is 13 to 4 for the stacked version. I doubt that he will ever have 720 teams :D But for general purpose yes, I admit you win ;) It's just weird that the stacked version takes 32x more memory when you have a small number of teams and only 4x more memory when you have a large number of teams :#

Comment: @ViktorKerkez It's not *so* weird, the stack is (pretty much) indep of number of teams, the defaultdict is completely dep. If there were just one team, defaultdict has to store one number (hehe in which case both are answers get confused), stack stores same as if there were lots. Also just noticed, I dislike the global variable/side effect in your function (but I'm not sure there is a neat way to pass the defaultdict in the arguments)...

Comment: @AndyHayden how is it independent when in one case it takes 32x more memory and in the other it takes only 4x more memory? And the global can be passed as an argument to apply, but that is not the an issue :)

Comment: Ah very good point, totally disingenous. That must be the groupby part (which has to create a hash table from the groups keys to the labels/positions), so more efficient for larger, but yeah dependent on size too. :p

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes sense to do a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and then `cumsum` each group. It's worth noting that this method will be **significantly** faster, than the Counter/defaultdict solution, when you have more items in your table *(I see it twice as fast by 100 rows and fifty times faster with 10000 rows)*.

First we have to [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) in such a way we can do this independently (of away/home):

```
In [10]: frame.columns = [['away', 'away', 'home', 'home'],
                          ['team', 'PTS', 'team', 'PTS']]

In [11]: frame  # with nice descriptive column labels
Out[11]: 
  away  away home  home
  team   PTS team   PTS
0  DET    88  CHI    92
1  CHI    75  ATL    88
2  HOU   105  SEA    95
3  TOR    99  DET    97
4  DAL   110  STL   100
5  STL    85  HOU    74
6  MIA    95  CHI    98
7  SEA   100  CHI   110

In [12]: frame_stacked = frame.stack(0)

In [13]: frame_stacked
Out[13]: 
        PTS team
0 away   88  DET
  home   92  CHI
1 away   75  CHI
  home   88  ATL
2 away  105  HOU
  home   95  SEA
3 away   99  TOR
  home   97  DET
4 away  110  DAL
  home  100  STL
5 away   85  STL
  home   74  HOU
6 away   95  MIA
  home   98  CHI
7 away  100  SEA
  home  110  CHI
```

Now we can groupby the team here (and cumsum will include both their away and home games):

```
In [14]: total_pts = frame_stacked.groupby('team')['PTS'].cumsum()

In [15]: total_pts
Out[15]: 
0  away     88
   home     92
1  away    167
   home     88
2  away    105
   home     95
3  away     99
   home    185
4  away    110
   home    100
5  away    185
   home    179
6  away     95
   home    265
7  away    195
   home    375
dtype: int64
```

Finally, we just have to insert these into the frame with the correctly named columns:

```
In [16]: frame[('home', 'totalPTS')] = total_pts[:, 'home']

In [17]: frame[('away', 'totalPTS')] = total_pts[:, 'away']

In [18]: frame
Out[18]: 
  away  away home  home     away     home
  team   PTS team   PTS totalPTS totalPTS
0  DET    88  CHI    92       88       92
1  CHI    75  ATL    88      167       88
2  HOU   105  SEA    95      105       95
3  TOR    99  DET    97       99      185
4  DAL   110  STL   100      110      100
5  STL    85  HOU    74      185      179
6  MIA    95  CHI    98       95      265
7  SEA   100  CHI   110      195      375
```